# Poner en edición una celda de DataGridView

Tags: c#

Esoy trabajando en una app windows forms, lo que quiero hacer es, al momento de crear una nueva fila selecciono y entre en edición la tercera columna.

```
dgvTalla.Rows.Add();
dgvTalla.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Selected = true;
dgvTalla.BeginEdit(true);
```

Con este código solo entra en edición la segunda columna, ¿Que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías establecer la celda activa e iniciar la edición en el evento RowsAdded del DataGridView:

```
    private void dgvTalla_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvTalla.CurrentCell = dgvTalla.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
        dgvTalla.BeginEdit(true);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Asier, como obtengo ese evento no lo encuentro, estoy usando visual studio 2015

Comment: Ya lo encontré, disculpa

Comment: Asier, estoy teniendo problemas con la técnica que me recomendaste para poner en edición la tercera columna de una fila, el problema es que, cuando llamo al formulario me crea una fila de la que ya existía y como tengo implementado el evento CellEndEdit lo persiste contra la DB, como puedo solucionarlo?